# Laravel Eloquent : two keys relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, eloquent, relationship

I have a first table named "Building", and this one gets a Type and a Level. There are multiple building with same type and level.
I have another table named "BuildingInfo", who also gets a Type and a Level. The couple Type/Level is unique on this table.

Is there a way to have a HasOne relationship on Building, giving me the matching BuildingInfo ? The problem being that there are two keys on each table to get it, and I can only specify one key for each table with HasOne().

Thank you.

Comment: If can change the database structure, you should replace the `type` and `level` column in the `buildings` table by `building_info_id` which refers to the `id` in the `building_info` table.

Comment: Actually the level column is subject to change on the buildings, and the type links to something else, so I can't do this.

Comment: Please provide a database diagram.

Comment: Just because you have two columns that can represent a key does not preclude you from adding an `id` column just to make things easier on you